# How to index and slice a multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the below multiindex dataframe, how can I slice it so that I select rows where the index `sign`== 1 and the column `csum_count == 8` ?

```
In [15]: raw3.head(20)
Out[15]:

                   csum_count  mean_return

sign cumsum

1    326              9        0.165
     854              9        0.081
     1346             9        0.055
     1440             9        0.157
     1554             9        0.069
     418              8        0.082
     578              8        0.119
     638              8        0.113
     896              8        0.076
     1480             8        0.059
     54               7        0.085
     446              7        0.120
     476              7        0.071
     484              7        0.094
     594              7        0.089
     622              7        0.069
     644              7        0.061
     1018             7        0.080
     1550             7        0.085
     1736             7        0.201
```

I'm able to select all rows with `sign == 1` via the following: `raw3.loc[(-1,)]`.  How do I add the additional criteria that `csum_count == 8?`. Thought that `raw3.loc[(-1,),'csum_count'==8]` might work but it didn't.

Comment: Maybe try with `raw3[raw3['sign'] == 1][raw3['csum_count' == 8]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter multi indices by calling `DataFrame.index.get_level_values()` and passing it the name (or level) of the index you want to slice on. In addition to that, you can add a condition on one of the columns.

```py
raw3[(raw3.index.get_level_values('sign') == 1) & (raw3[csum_count == 8])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .query() method for DataFrames, and pass a boolean string.

In your case, `raw3.query('sign == 1 and cumsum == 8')` should give you the result you want.